# declared variable expression conversion

Tags: ssrs-2012

Can anyone help me convert the following lines to `SSRS` expressions?  I'm trying to return the dates in my `SSRS` report so users can see the data ranges they are returning data for.  My data set queries are using the these to set the date parameters.  Some of the functions don't seem to work in `SSRS`.

```
EOMONTH(Dateadd(Quarter,Datediff(Quarter,0,getdate())-2,0),2) --Beg of last Quarter   

EOMONTH(Dateadd(Quarter,Datediff(Quarter,0,getdate())-1,0),2) --end of last Quarter

EOMONTH(Dateadd(Year,Datediff(Year,0,getdate())-1,0),11) --beg this year

EOMONTH(Dateadd(Year,Datediff(Year,0,getdate())-2,0),11) -- beg of last year

EOMONTH(Dateadd(Year,Datediff(Year,0,getdate())-1,0),11) -- end of last year
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this can help you

beginning of last Quarter `=FormatDateTime(dateadd("q",datediff("q","1/1/1900",today)-1,"1/1/1900"),DateFormat.ShortDate)`

end of last quarter

```
=FormatDateTime(dateadd("s",-1,dateadd("q",datediff("q","1/1/1900",today),"1/1/1900")),DateFormat.ShortDate)
```

Beginning of current year

```
=FormatDateTime(DateSerial(YEAR(Today),1,1),DateFormat.ShortDate)
```

End of current year

```
=FormatDateTime(DateSerial(Year(Now), 12, 31),DateFormat.ShortDate)
```

Beginning of the last year

```
=FormatDateTime(DateSerial(YEAR(Today)-1,1,1),DateFormat.ShortDate)
```

End of the last year

```
=FormatDateTime(DateSerial(Year(Now)-1, 12, 31),DateFormat.ShortDate)
```

Note I am using FormatDateTime to get short date, you can set the format as your requeriments.